# Using jsonlite to parse json string with number labels

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm retrieving a json string from an API (over which I have no control) that looks like the following:

```
{
     "data": [
     {
         "6": {
             "value": "Jamie Stein"
         },
         "7": {
             "value": 10
         }
     },
     {
         "6": {
             "value": "Bill Smith"
         },
         "7": {
             "value": 23
         }
     }
     ],
     "fields": [
     {
         "id": 6,
         "label": "Full Name"
     },
     {
         "id": 7,
         "label": "Amount"
     }
     ]
 }
```

I'm using `fromJSON` from the *jsonlite* package (version 1.7.0) to parse the string:
`res <- from JSON(jsonstr)`.

The resulting *data* dataframe has names that are corrupted.  The result looks like this:

```
> res
$data
        value value
1 Jamie Stein    10
2  Bill Smith    23

$fields
  id     label
1  6 Full Name
2  7    Amount
```

Notice the "value" column names in the *data* dataframe.  I can update the column names for the *data* dataframe, but that seems to make things even weirder:

```
> get_label <- function(x) { res$fields$label[res$fields$id == x]}
> names(res$data) <- sapply(as.integer(names(res$data)), get_label)
> names(res$data)
[1] "Full Name" "Amount"   
> res$data
        value value
1 Jamie Stein    10
2  Bill Smith    23
```

The *names* function indicates that the column names have been updated, but just printing the dataframe indicates that the column names are still corrupted.

Can someone help me understand what is going on and what I can do about it?  I'm befuddled at this point.  The corrupted dataframe is problematic - when I use *write.csv*, the resulting file is garbage.

Also, if helpful, the version of R I'm running is 4.0.2.

Comment: `str(res)` shows that `data` is not a clean `data.frame`. When you run that, see that `fields` looks like a frame *should*, whereas `data` is a nested-frame of sorts. Are you needing to preserve the ids 6 and 7, or just discard them and end up with a "normal" `data` frame?

Comment: @r2evans - the 6 and 7 are used for the mapping to the field label.  The data the API is returning has an ID associated with it (the 6 or 7) and with each ID has a corresponding label (the "Full Name" and "Amount" labels).  Labels can change over time, while the ID is permanent - I believe that is why the API is designed to return the data in this particular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, strange. You can do:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr) # to use 'transpose'
obj <- fromJSON(json, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
lapply(obj, function(x){
  as.data.frame(lapply(transpose(x), unlist))
})
# $data
#            X6 X7
# 1 Jamie Stein 10
# 2  Bill Smith 23
# 
# $fields
#   id     label
# 1  6 Full Name
# 2  7    Amount
```

To get column names `"6"` and `"7"`:

```
lapply(obj, function(x){
  as.data.frame(lapply(transpose(x), unlist), check.names = FALSE)
})
# $data
#             6  7
# 1 Jamie Stein 10
# 2  Bill Smith 23
# 
# $fields
#   id     label
# 1  6 Full Name
# 2  7    Amount
```

---

## EDIT: simpler way

Not strange actually...

```
obj <- fromJSON(json)
```

`obj$data` is a dataframe, but its columns are dataframes as well:

```
> str(obj$data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ 6:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ value: chr  "Jamie Stein" "Bill Smith"
 $ 7:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ value: int  10 23
```

Then you want:

```
obj$data <- as.data.frame(lapply(obj$data, "[[", "value"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  This gets me past my bottleneck, but I still don't understand what is going on.  For example, I thought that the column names shown by displaying a dataframe would always be the same as the column names shown by calling the names() function on the dataframe.  The fact that in this case they are different is new to me.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  Each column of the *data* dataframe, instead of being a vector, was itself a one-column dataframe.  Thus there were two levels of dataframes.  When I called names on the top level, it showed me the names associated with the top level columns.  But when I displayed the top level dataframe as a whole, it displayed the names associated with the lower level dataframe.

That's messed up, but that certainly explains what I was observing.  Thank you for your help.